# Create event across days in CalendarKit

Tags: ios, swift, calendarkit

Is it possible to create an event with a different start date and time and end date and time?

Example

```
start date is 2021-04-15 23:00

end date is   2021-04-16 02:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

In your DataSource method `func eventsForDate(_ date: Date) -> [EventDescriptor]` include the event in the returned array if it occurs in a given date.

For example, if the event starts 15:00 1st Jan and ends 16:30 3rd Jan, you'll need to return that event in the payload for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd January.

CK should handle the layout and display of the events.

Comment: Thank your for answer!


FYI, I'm using v0.4.0 that include some bugs, so I have to update 0.14+.

Comment: I got this info from Richard by e-mail.